# AngularJS - alternative use for isolated scope expressions ("&")

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I know `"&"` binding used to pass the method (expressions) to directives isolate scope, so the directive will able to execute it when needed.

Many times I need to "pass" the same expression from my main controller, more than one level deep, to nested directive (2-3 levels). This why on my own, I don't like to use `"&"` for that purpose. For me, sending "callbacks" using `"="` bindings works much better. But this is not a question.

The question is:
What for, I can use `"&"` in addition to passing functions? 
Can I have something like this: `my-directive-click="clickCount +=1"`?

Answer (score 1):

`&` is more about allowing you to deal with expressions, and more importantly (in my eyes) allows you to place parameters into the calling parent's scope.

For instance if you have:

```
scope: {
    something: '&'
}
```

and then in that directives template you could do:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-change="something({$item: selection})" ...>
```

The caller/user of this directive than can ACCESS $item in the expression passed to `something`, i.e. $item is placed on its scope.

e.g.

```
<my-dir something="myOwnVar = $item + 1"></my-dir>
```

here is a plunker with an example of this, including chaining (multiple nested calls of a `&` expression):
 http://plnkr.co/edit/j4FCBIx0FVz4OT0w50bU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In reality, the `&` is meant as one-way-data-binding.

So `=` is two-way-data-binding which means changes done on the directive will persist to the original object.

`@` is just a string.

And `&` is special. The thing is that it creates a getter for your value, in the case of an invoked function, the getter actually calls the function. I tend to do this on the DDO:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {      
      getParameters: '&?params'
    }
```

So in this way, the value bound to the `scope` is `getParameters` (so it's clear is a getter) but on the directive element you will only refer it as `params`:

```
<my-directive params="ctrl.params">
```

Your question is vague though and even though you may be able to do what you were asking, I think it would be best to do that inside the directive rather than the way you proposed.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I didn't look on `&` it as getter. It was always an expression for me. That way I try to update the state or execute the behavior on "parent" controller, even when I need to "get" value. The problem with `&` even for "get" is, if to get value I need to pass a parameters from 2 level nested directive (one or more parameters), than I have headache...I didn't found an easy way to do it. But with "=" it works very easy. BTW, I think "=" is "two way binding" only in case of "referenced type". I don't think the valued type will change on parent if directive changes it, but maybe I'm wrong here :)

Comment: If you're passing parameters to get things then you should be using a Service IMHO. Regarding your thoughts, `=` will persist changes on parent if done on directive. Check this plunker to see your concern in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/DbYYbAsCc5T2XdsRJpSw?p=preview

Comment: @AntonioLaguna yes if you pass a primitive like a string or number 
then your directive will not be able to modify it back on parent scope. If you wrap your primitive in an object it will be modified.

Comment: @szydan the plnkr I pasted is using a primitive, not an object.